# Клик по кнопке при скролле блока более чем на 3px

Tags: javascript

есть 5 кнопок, у каждой из которой есть атрибут href который при нажатии на него скролит страницу до соответствующего блока с id. Нужно написать скрипт на javascript который бы при прокрутке каждого блока более чем на 3 пикселя от вверха страницы нажимал на кнопку соответствующую следующему  за ним блоку. То есть чтобы получался поэкранный скролл.

Пока это реализовано так, но не работает

html

```
            <button class="scrollbar_item scrollbar_item-1" href="#head1" onclick="toggleActiveClass(event)"></button>
            <button class="scrollbar_item scrollbar_item-2" href="#head2" onclick="toggleActiveClass(event)"></button>
            <button class="scrollbar_item scrollbar_item-3" href="#head3" onclick="toggleActiveClass(event)"></button>
            <button class="scrollbar_item scrollbar_item-4" href="#head4" onclick="toggleActiveClass(event)"></button>
            <button class="scrollbar_item scrollbar_item-5" href="#head5" onclick="toggleActiveClass(event)"></button>

    <div class="" id="head1" style="height: 100vh; width: 500px;"></div>
    <div class="" id="head2" style="height: 100vh; width: 500px;"></div>
    <div class="" id="head3" style="height: 100vh; width: 500px;"></div>
    <div class="" id="head4" style="height: 100vh; width: 500px;"></div>
    <div class="" id="head5" style="height: 100vh; width: 500px;"></div>
```

js

```
  let blocks = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="head"]');
  for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    
    let block = blocks[i];

    let nextBlock = blocks[i+1];



    let blockPosition = block.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (blockPosition > 3) {
      let button = document.querySelector('scrollbar_item[href="#' + nextBlock.id + '"]');
      button.click();
      
    }
  }
```